# Don't run code during autosave in save_post on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type in Wordpress and I want to run a custom code when the post is published. Not during the autosave or update.

```
function send_notification($post_id, $post){

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
        return;
    }

    if (get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'vip_post') {
         send_message($post->post_content);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'send_notification', 10, 2);
```

However, I found that the function `send_message` is getting triggered multiple times while I am writing something in the Post Editor and before I click on publish button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `did_action` to check action already called? try the below code.

```
function send_notification($post_id, $post){

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
        return;
    }

    $times = did_action('save_post');
    if( $times === 1 ){
        if (get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'vip_post') {
             send_message($post->post_content);
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_notification', 10, 2 );
```

**An alternative version of the above code with an early return.**

```
function send_notification($post_id, $post){

    if ( did_action( 'save_post' ) > 1 ){
        return; 
    } 

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
        return;
    }

    if (get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'vip_post') {
         send_message($post->post_content);
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_notification', 10, 2 );
```

**Also, You can remove your action using the `remove_action` hook. once your function is called.**

```
function send_notification($post_id, $post){

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision ) {
        return;
    }

    if (get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'vip_post') {
         send_message($post->post_content);
    }

    remove_action('post_save', 'send_notification');

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'send_notification', 10, 2 );
```

**OR**

You can completely disable it by deregistering the script using `wp_deregister_script`. try below code.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_autosave' );
function disable_autosave() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'autosave' );
}
```

Comment: This will disable autosave and it's not what I want to do. As I explain, I try to run a code only when a post is published, but it runs during the autosave as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer.